# Preg_replace with brackets [ ] inside

Tags: php, regex

I am now creating a shortcode by using     `preg_replace`.

```
$content = preg_replace(
    '%\[social-lock]([^[]*)\[/social-lock]%',
    $html_str_1. '\1' . $html_str_2 . '<br/>' . $html_js,
    $content
    );
echo $content;
```

When I apply this shortcode to HTML content, we will have something like that

```
Below content will be hidden. 

[social-lock]
Code Vip: Write something here.
[/social-lock].
```

The output to browser will show :

```
Below content will be hidden. 
<div class="lock" style="display:none">
Code Vip: Write something here.
</div>
```

But if I add brackets inside the HTML content (between the social-lock), like that :

```
Below content will be hidden. 

[social-lock]
Code Vip: Write something here. [show the brackets here]
and it will not be hidden.
[/social-lock].
```

The content inside [social-lock] - [/social-lock] should be hidden but it's not. I think that because of brackets [ ] inside the content of shortcode. 
But I find no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks because you use this `([^[]*)` which says every character except `[` between 0 and unlimited times. So it stops at `[` in your string.

To solve this you can use `(.*?)`, which says get everything between 0 and unlimited times, but lazy. Also make sure to set the flag `s`, so `.` also can match over new lines.

Comment: My code also replace the `[social-lock]` and put the inside content to new div. I tried `(.*?)` but no luck.

Comment: @AluminumGates As I said, you also need to set the flag `s`: https://regex101.com/r/zR1rC5/1

Comment: You saved my life ! I forgot /s. Thanks !